# what causes sudded increase in size of WiredTigerHS.wt in mongodb5.0

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have mongodb 5.0.8 on linux

We run multiple clusters but I see that on one cluster , with 3 shards there is a simultaneous increase on all shard servers  in WiredTigerHS.wt  file at times in my mongo data dir

This grows by almost 100GB in an hour ... while my total data size ( on disk ) is just 600GB per shard . The file grew to 470GB and filled up the disk

This does not happen all the time. I stopped the mongos on the cluster and then rebuilt the shard. Not the file is 50GB

Now , I changed this setting to  ( But I am not sure on this )

```
"minSnapshotHistoryWindowInSeconds" : 10
```

What is causing this sudden increase in file size ?
how can i control it ?
If it is increasing what should I do so that I dont run out of disk ?

Comment: Did you have a look at your logfiles?

Comment: What should I look for in the logs  , the servers are pretty busy there is no error in the logs but lots of other general messages

Comment: Check with [jq](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/log-messages/#pretty-printing) for errors or warnings.